# Migrate login details from php/mysql to asp/sqlserver

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, data-migration, login-control

I have a website in php which I have converted all the pages to .aspx but the website has login/signup pages.

I`d like to know how I could transfer the already existing login details to an sql server table, since the passwords are hashed(scrambled) in the mysql table?

I plan on using a Login control in asp.net, for a form-based authentication on the login/signup pages.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Implements the same logic in ASP than you have in PHP, a hash is a hash no matter the language your are handling with.

Comment: Thanks Mario....but am newbie in this area, I have the username and salted passwords in a table from the php webpage and i plan to create a login page on asp.net. My challenge is how to make the login control  to match the username with the salted password, to enable already registered users in the new asp.net login page. THANKS